# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date. "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss" format

Tags: java, simpledateformat, parseexception

I am getting a parsing error with the following code

```
String time = "24 Apr 2021 11:56:44";
Date timeOnLine = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(time);
```

Exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "24 Apr 2021 11:56:44"

I am not sure what the problem is since the pattern seems to correspond with the string correctly.

Any advice on how to solve would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is "Apr" actually "April" in the default locale of wherever this code is running on?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
String time = "24 Apr 2021 11:56:44";
Date timeOnLine = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).parse(time);
```